# How to call a function inside a class that's need login?

Tags: php, api

I'm using an api, example:

```
// Log in:
$obj = new example('username', 'password');

// Get your feed:
$snaps = $obj->feed();

// Get your friends' stories:
$stories = $obj->stories();
```

But in the api theres a register function that's under example->register but how do i use it if I need to login to use the rest, specifically how would I use the register function for https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat

Comment: `$snapchat = new Snapchat(); $snapchat->register( ... );` - the constructors parameters are all optional, so you don't **have** to pass a username and password, but you can if you have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the `__construct` (the method which is called when creating a new Snapchat object) parameters are optional. As you can see here, they all have a default value of `null`.

```
public function __construct($username = NULL, $password = NULL, $auth_token = NULL) {
```

This means you can pass no parameters and it will still create an instance. So to answer your question, you would do it like this.

```
$snapchat = new Snapchat(); 
$snapchat->register($username, $password, $email, $birthday);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, I'm guessing there a problem with the api that it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the constructor without username and password like this

```
$obj = new Snapchat();
$obj->register('username', 'password');
```